# How to disable scroll to zoom. Google Maps Embed API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

Can anyone tell me how to disable scrolling when using the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)?

I am building a site which requires an embedded map in the middle of a page which users need to be able to scroll past without accidentally engaging the zoom feature.

I tried taking the necessary argument from the javascript api and supplying is as part of the arguments in the url string.

```
scrollwheel: false
```

Reformatted to:

```
&scrollwheel=false
```

This did not work. Instead of a map, I then get "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Unexpected parameter 'scrollwheel'."

If there is no legit way to achieve this via the embed api, can anyone recommend a hackier solution? I still want people to be able to interact with the map via onscreeen buttons so I can't simply overlay a transparent div, or disable pointer events.

I am asking specifically about Google Maps Embed API. I am not interested in solutions which would require the using the Google Maps JavaScript API instead. For this project I am not able to switch to the JS API.

This is not a duplicate question, it is a different API and no one on SA has answered how to disable scrolling with the Embed API.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation for embeds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters), I cannot see any way using the request URL to disable zoom.

However, you may want to see [this post from this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330197/how-to-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-scaling-with-google-maps-api) to see about an alternative. It will not be an embed, but it will be the next best thing.