# step by step instructions for eliminating scrollwheel zoom in google maps

Tags: google-maps

i found a thread that shows the scrollwheel code line that needs to be set to false for stopping the annoying scrollwheel zoom.  but I can't post on that page because i don't have a 10 reputation and apparently it drew some kind of spam . . . so sorry for redundancy.

my problem is i don't know where to find this code or how to open it and change it. It seems this might be browser dependent but i'm unclear on that. i'm running Firefox 47 on a Mac Air System 10.10.5

it drives me absolutely crazy that google wouldn't just provide a toogle for this feature which takes over a standard function of the operating system, esp. since 99% of the time you can's scroll by using the arrow keys without standing on your head and whistling the star spangled banner backwards so not only is the instinctive speed of sound zooming absurd but i have no way to scroll the display without the carpel tunnel inducing click-hold-move cursor

i have no clue what made them think zooming was more important than scrolling. i suppose the only advantage is i might learn something low level about coding to these interfaces.

thanks if anyone can walk me through this step by step.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make the above mentioned "no-scroll map" by embedding it right into your website using an `<iframe>` tag, I would suggest you see [this](https://github.com/kylelam/kylelam.github.io/blob/master/iframe.html) great solution provided by [Kaho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4561511/kaho). Demo page: http://kylelam.github.io/iframe.html

Comment: an iframe* tag I meant

Comment: Damien,
what i'm really trying to do is to set the browser for no zoom by scrollwheel, not for no scrolling, anytime i visit googlemaps. from reading other threads i think i need to set the "scrollwheel" property to "false" but these threads presume that i know where to find the properties and how to reset them which i do not. this is the thread that references the "scrollwheel" property. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330197/how-to-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-scaling-with-google-maps-api?newreg=cb869b7152b040609c7db1443cfb3d8c