# Greasemonkey script: for Google Maps to disable Zoom on Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, greasemonkey

As a desktop browser user of Google Maps I'd like to switch off the Zooming that occurs every time I use my touch-pad two-finger gesture to scroll up/down.

How do I get hold of the appropriate DOM object handle?
So I can script Greasemonkey (or similar) to set the `scrollwheel` option to `false` as shown in this previous answer (which is for developers who use the GoogleMap API on their own sites)
[How to disable mouse scroll wheel scaling with Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330197/how-to-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-scaling-with-google-maps-api)

Comment: You need to find the javascript variable where that page stores the return from the `new google.maps.Map()` call.  Then your script can hook into it (although *possibly* in Firefox only -- depending on how evil that page is).

Comment: I've tried to do that using Firefox's Inspector but it is hard to know where to inspect.

Comment: Hence why I haven't done it for you. ;)   Still, needs must if you want to script a Maps page, and it can be done, it's just work...